# How to include png++/libpng for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, png, libpng

can anybody help me how to use png++/libpng in a Visual Studio Project? 
For Linux there are several tutorials and examples, but for the usage in a Visual studio project I found no help.

My CMakeLists.txt-file looks this way:

```
# project
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (libviso2)

# directories
set (LIBVISO2_SRC_DIR src)

# include directory
include_directories("${LIBVISO2_SRC_DIR}")

# use sse3 instruction set
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse3")

# sources
FILE(GLOB LIBVISO2_SRC_FILES "src/*.cpp")

# make release version
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

# demo program
add_executable(viso2 ${LIBVISO2_SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries (viso2 png)
```

Using CMake GUI and the above CMakeLists.txt-file I can generate a Visual Studio Project that works fine for itself until the png++-algorithms are handled in the code (build error). So basically my problem is that I have no experience in CMake and png++/libpng.

I have two folders downloaded from the web, one folder png++ and one folder libpng. 
In these two folders there is all the code for the two libraries.

So my question is:

1. Could anybody explain to me how to arrange/include these two folders in a Visual Studio project producing no error, this could be a very simple project starting:

   #include "png++/png.hpp"
    using namespace png;
2. How would I edit the CMakeLists file in order to build a Visual studio project in which the png++ and libpng folders are correctly included so as to make it feasible to use the png++ code?

Thank You in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

png++ is a C++ wrapper for libpng library, so it only has header files.

what you need to do is to compile libpng and its dependency(zlib).

and include header files of png++, libpng and zlib, add library of libpng and zlib.

That's all you need, I ran libviso2 successfully on Windows, good luck!